# Instloader - Facing issue while getting profile information using username, previously It was working

Tags: python, instagram-api, instaloader

Library Link: https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader

```py
import instaloader
 
ACCOUNT_USERNAME=""
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD=""
# Creating an instance of the Instaloader class
bot = instaloader.Instaloader()
bot.login(ACCOUNT_USERNAME, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD)
 
username = "instagram"
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(bot.context, username)
print("Trying to scrape profile of:", profile.username)
print("Number of Posts: ", profile.mediacount)
print("Followers Count: ", profile.followers)
print("Following Count: ", profile.followees)
```

I'm trying to run the above code but facing the bellow issue,

issue:

```
HTTP redirect from https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=instagram to Number of requests within last 10/11/20/22/30/60 minutes grouped by type:
                              other:    1    1    1    1    1    1
 *                           iphone:    1    1    1    1    1    1
Instagram responded with HTTP error "429 - Too Many Requests". Please
do not run multiple instances of Instaloader in parallel or within
short sequence. Also, do not use any Instagram App while Instaloader
is running.
The request will be retried in 30 minutes, at 18:04.
```

can anyone please help me to resolve this? After every 30 mins, it's saying the same thing again and again, any resolution?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to `pip`